# Specific data types

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to build a database but i'm struggling with the type of some data.
Basicly i would like to have something that behave like a combobox : you have several choices but can only choose one.
Unfortunatly i can't define that in a sql database.
I came up with the idea to store all the different "choices" in a table and each entries will fill one, leaving 10+ empty field.

Isn't there another method to do this in a cleaner way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Enumerated types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/datatype-enum.html) behave as you describe.